# How to properly pass functions to other functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to understand the way that javascript passes functions around and am having a bit of a problem groking why a prototype function can NOT access a var defined in a function constructor while a function defined in the constructor can access the var.  Here is code that works:

```
   var model = function model() {
       this.state = 1;
       this.GetState =   (function(scope){
           return function(){ return scope.state;};
       })(this);
   }

    var othermodel = function othermodel(mdl) {
        this.GetStateFn = mdl.GetState;
    }

    othermodel.prototype.WriteState = function() {
        console.log(this.GetStateFn.call());
    };

    var m = new model();
    var o = new othermodel(m)


    o.WriteState();
```

This works and makes sense - the GetState() function can access this.state.

However, if I create GetState as follows:

```
 model.prototype.GetState =   (function(scope){
        return function(){ return scope.state;};
    })(this);
```

The result will be an error that scope is not defined.

I would prefer to have this work with the prototype method as I do not want a copy of the function in ever model, but it would seem that prototype can't work because it can't access the specific instance of the model.

So, can someone provide me with a good explanation of a) what I need to do to get this to work with prototype (assuming I can) and b) if I can't get it to work with prototype, what is the reason so I can understand better the underpinnings of the issue.

Comment: I had thought about that, but that would create a circular ref as mdl actually refers to othermodel already in our real world project.  I'm going to rethink this architecture - I don't think the circular ref will cause a problem, but it makes me uneasy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply write the function this way

```
model.prototype.GetState = function() { return this.state; }

var othermodel = function othermodel(mdl) {
    this.GetStateFn = mdl.GetState.bind(mdl);
}

othermodel.prototype.WriteState = function() {
    console.log(this.GetStateFn.call());
};
```

The above code will work, as in most cases you will execute code like `m.GetState()`. That is an example of invoking a function as an object method. In that case, `this` is guaranteed to point to the object `m`. You seem to know how the prototype chains work, so I won't go there.

When assigning the function reference to the other model, we use the `.bind` to ensure that within `GetState`, `this` points to `mdl`. Reference for `bind`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Your original IIFE's were in effect your implementation of bind. The issue was the value of `this` was wrong. Currently, every time you need to assign models function to some other function, you will need to use `bind` at all those times. You have tagged your question as node.js, `bind` is available on the `Function` prototype in node.js and any ES5 compatible browser. If you need to run the above code on older browsers or environments that do not support `bind`, replace `bind` with your IIFE.

As for why your code isn't working,

```
model.prototype.GetState =   (function(scope){
    return function(){ return scope.state;};
})(this);
```

Here, `this` doesn't refer to the eventual model object (`m`). `this` can refer to any one of 5 options in javascript. Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Lets assume the above code is in an html file inside some script tag. Then `this` will refer to the window object. `window` doesn't have any property called `state`, hence the `undefined`. If you were to `console.log(this.m, this.o)` at the end of you script, you would see the respective `m` and `o` objects.

Comment: You can't assume "in most cases you will execute code like `m.GetState()`". The code the OP provided is a perfect example of why your code won't work either and isn't a solution.

Comment: How do I redefine "this" so that it will refer to a new instance of the model object?  That's where I get very confused.  And then how do I assign GetState to othermodel such that I can then execute WriteState from othermodel and get the correct model.state value for a specific instance of model?

Comment: @Ian, True. I missed modifying the two functions in `othermodel`. I think this should work now.

Comment: @AlexGad, updated the answer. As such I find MDN to be a very good JS documentation resource.

Comment: Perfect, that now works. Thanks! I was playing around with bind and call and just did not have the right combo.  One followup question, the reason for this whole exercise was that I wanted to avoid copying around the model instance because its a huge object in our real world app and I wanted to avoid potential circular references.  If I have to do the above to accomplish passing functions, should I simply pass the model instance to the othermodel, set this.mdl = mdl in the constructor and then just call this.mdl.state?  Any benefit to passing the function instead of the entire model object?

Comment: @AlexGad If the above works for you, don't bother storing `mdl` as a property, unless you have many things to access in it. In your example, you just needed a reference to the one method, so it made sense to just reference that only.

Comment: You could do that. You will be passing references around. Not the actual objects. The memory consumption of these references will pale in front the actual huge object.

Comment: @AlexGad, The `.call` in `this.GetStateFn.call()` is not needed. The MDN documentation explains some use cases for `.call`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call ...

Comment: Yea, I actually have a lot that I need to access so storing mdl as a property makes sense.  The only problem is that would create a circular reference since mdl stores a reference to othermodel as well.  I don't think that will cause problems as mdl is actually very short lived, but I need to think this through as the code stink is starting to worry me.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

When defined like this:

```
var model = function model() {
    this.state = 1;
    this.GetState =   (function(scope){
        return function(){ return scope.state;};
    })(this);
}
```

the anonymous function is declared and immediately executed. `this` is passed as a parameter to that self-executing function. As a result - a new function is returned, but this function has `scope` parameter in its closure - so that it is accessible after the scope has exited. As a result - the function, when invoked, can still access `state` property of that "enclosed" `this` (the one that became `scope` and was closed upon).

If you define it like this:

```
model.prototype.GetState =   (function(scope){
    return function(){ return scope.state;};
})(this);
```

the mechanism is the same, it's just `this` is not. It is now the context of the scope you execute the above code in. Assuming it's done in global scope - it would be `window` object.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `bind` because of its support with older browsers, you could try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/j7h97/1/

```
var model = function (state) {
    this.state = state || new Date().getTime();
};

model.prototype.GetState = function () {
    return this.state;
};

model.prototype.WriteState = function () {
    console.log("model WriteState: " + this.GetState());
};

var othermodel = function othermodel (mdl) {
    this.GetStateFn = function () {
        return mdl.GetState.call(mdl);
    };
};

othermodel.prototype.WriteState = function () {
    console.log("othermodel WriteState: " + this.GetStateFn());
};

var model1 = new model();
model1.WriteState();
var othermodel1 = new othermodel(model1);
othermodel1.WriteState();

var model2 = new model();
model2.WriteState();
var othermodel2 = new othermodel(model2);
othermodel2.WriteState();
```

Seems to do what you want without `bind`. I created the `model.prototype.WriteState` for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where it is called. If it's in global scope, `this` will not refer the the model. If it's running in a browser it will refer to the global `window` object instead.